# How to run GAM with raster package?

Tags: raster, r, error, gam

When I am using the raster package to predict a surface probability map of species distribution using the following functions in R, the following error occurrs:

```
CA132122200=raster("F:/CBG maps-UnProj/anlytic final map/mov472/landmergbackg1.tif_mw2/ca_132.tif")
mod=gam(y~s(CA132122200) ,data=training, family=binomial, gamma=1.4, logLink="logit")
 prediction <- predict(object = CA132122200, model = mod, type='response', progress='text')

errors:
object is not a matrix:
In addition: Warning messages:

1: In predict.gam(model, blockvals, ...) :
  not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!

2: 'newdata' had 2032869 rows but variables found have 2315 rows"
```